# I want to produce a scrolling image

Tags: ffmpeg, effects

I have an image (say .png) of big vertical size. I want to create a video that shows this image slowly scrolling from the top to the bottom. How?

ffmpeg? pymovie?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528803/856090

Comment: you could use scroll filter in combination of crop filter after scroll one.

Answer (score 1):

Most quality editing (Adobe Premier, Final Cut, etc.) will allow you to do this pretty easily with both text and images using "keyframing". You can make them scroll, zoom in, or whatever other movement you need. There's tons of videos on how to do this on Youtube, but here's one for Adobe Premier:

Comment: I think he's asking how to do it programmatically, which he didn't really make clear in the question.  Your answer isn't so bad that it deserves a downvote.